# RVM installation does not work, how should I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails. I am trying to follow jump start with rails book and I am unable to move from second chapter.

```
MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:rails_projects MyThReYa$ rvm use --create 2.0.0@training
ruby-2.0.0-p353 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353'
MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:rails_projects MyThReYa$
```

When I try to use the rvm install this is the result:

```
MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:rails_projects MyThReYa$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p353.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on 
binary rubies.
You requested building with '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.
```

I have also tried installing previous versions still getting the same error.

How do I fix it?

```
MyThReYas-MacBook-Pro:rails_projects MyThReYa$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-
include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1   
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: show `gcc -v` commnad

Comment: `gcc` cannot be found. Did you install Command Line Tools in Xcode ?

Comment: install the Xcode command line tools. installing macport helps. install macport and then install joe. than macport starts asking if like to install Xcode commnandline tools. but there is for sure an easy way as well

Comment: i think i did installed x-code command line tools

Comment: on which system did you ruby the `rvm`? show also `uname -a`

Comment: i have only one and i did on the same user name that you see in the above terminal code

Comment: `xcode-select --install` and install command tools

Comment: is there any way i can check whether command tools are installed or not ?.

Comment: @Amit try 1. remove version, 2. add version `p247`

Comment: Also do a `rvm get head` just to be sure RVM is up to date.